# Почему происходят ошибки "incompatible types required" и "constructor cannot be applied to given types"?

Tags: java

Мне нужно устранить все ошибки компиляции.

Вот мой код:

```
class Ball{
        private int radius;
        private final int defaultRadius;
        public Ball(){
            defaultRadius = 20;
            radius = calculateRadius();
        }
        public Ball(boolean isDoubled){
            if (isDoubled)
                radius <<= 1;
            
        }
        protected int calculateRadius(){
            return defaultRadius;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return radius;
        }
}
class BigBall extends Ball{
    private int radiusInc = 30;
    protected int calculateRadius(){
        return defaultRadius+radiusInc;
    }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        System.out.println(new Ball());
        System.out.println(new Ball(true));
        System.out.println(new BigBall());
        System.out.println(new BigBall(true));
    }
}
```

Вот ошибки:

```
Error:(17, 16) java: incompatible types required: java.lang.String found: int

Error:(24, 16) java: defaultRadius has private access in Ball

Error:(32, 28) java: constructor BigBall in class BigBall cannot be applied to given types; 
required: no arguments found: boolean reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: А какие мысли есть у Вас? Задание элементарное.

Comment: @post_zeew Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.Я запутался

Comment: госпаде: `return radius` - `radius` заявлен как `int`, а метод ожидает `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> incompatible types required: java.lang.String found: int

Говорит о том, что возвращаемый тип метода должен быть `String`, а он сейчас `int`

Чтобы привести в нужный вид, нужно возвращать то, что требуют:

```
public String toString(){
    return String.valueOf(radius);
}
```

> defaultRadius has private access in Ball

Модификатор доступа у `defaultRadius` объявлен как приватный, а значит достучаться к полю можно через метод `calculateRadius()`. Вдобавок он объявлен как `final`, а значит брать значение можно только с базового класса. Это значит, что здесь:

```
protected int calculateRadius(){
    return defaultRadius+radiusInc;
}
```

можно записать так:

```
protected int calculateRadius(){
    return super.calculateRadius()+radiusInc;
}
```

> constructor BigBall in class BigBall cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: boolean reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Говорит о том, что в строке

```
System.out.println(new BigBall(true));
```

Дается конструктору параметр, хотя в классе `BigBall` нет такого конструктора.

лечится добавлением оного:

```
public BigBall(boolean isDoubled){
    super(isDoubled);
}
```

Правда тогда пропадает конструктор по умолчанию, который компилятор автоматически всегда создает для классов, а значит для `new BigBall()` теперь нужно конструктор по умолчанию создать ручками:

```
public BigBall(){
    super();
}
```

и еще. Т.к. `defaultRadius` объявлен как `final`, то изменять это значение нельзя. А значит значение нужно сразу инициализировать

```
private final int defaultRadius = 10;
```

а также нельзя пытаться изменить это значение здесь:

```
public Ball(){
    defaultRadius = 20; <!---- Это нужно удалить
    radius = calculateRadius();
}
```

---

Результат может выглядеть как-то так:

```
class Ball{
    private int radius;
    private final int defaultRadius = 10;

    public Ball(){    
        radius = calculateRadius();
    }
    public Ball(boolean isDoubled){
        // вызов конструктора по умолчанию,  
        // иначе не будет инициализирован radius
        this();

        if (isDoubled)
            radius <<= 1;

    }
    protected int calculateRadius(){
        return defaultRadius;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(radius);
    }
}
class BigBall extends Ball{
    private int radiusInc = 30;
    public BigBall(){
        super();
    }
    public BigBall(boolean isDoubled){
        super(isDoubled);
    }
    protected int calculateRadius(){
        return super.calculateRadius()+radiusInc;
    }
}
```

main без изменений

```
System.out.println(new Ball());
System.out.println(new Ball(true));
System.out.println(new BigBall());
System.out.println(new BigBall(true));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, теперь понял все!

Comment: `defaultRadius = 20; <!---- Это нужно удалить` удалять не нужно, нужно в `public Ball(boolean isDoubled)` добавить вызов конструктора без параметров, иначе не будет инициализирован `radius`.

Comment: @zRrr `нужно в public Ball(boolean isDoubled) добавить вызов конструктора без параметров, иначе не будет инициализирован radius` -  да, упустил из виду ...........`defaultRadius = 20; <!---- Это нужно удалить удалять не нужно,` - почему?

Comment: @DenisTsay  нужно в public Ball(boolean isDoubled) добавить вызов конструктора без параметров, иначе не будет инициализирован radius  еще

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто необязательно, `final` поля можно инициализировать в конструкторе. Там есть еще проблема с `BigBall.calculateRadius`, который использует `radiusInc`, но вызывается из конструктора суперкласса до ее инициализации и прибавляет 0. Проблему, в принципе, решает объявление `radiusInc` `final`, но поскольку в задании просят устранить только ошибки компиляции, то сойдет и так :)

Comment: @zRrr ну да .... http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/3/2/1/8052123.jpg   )))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может там три задания: исправить ошибки компиляции; исправить программу; рассказать, почему не надо так делать

Comment: @zRrr а может там зашифровано послание с другой вселенной параллельного мира, где нам дается единственный шанс найти наконец лекарство от всех болезней и прекращения войн, а также возможность слиться в едином информационно-энергетическом потоке с космосом и обрести успокоение ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почему в итоге выводит 10 20 10 20. Не понятны действия radius <<=1

Comment: @DenisTsay а что ты ожидаешь на выходе?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не понятно чему равна переменная radius

Comment: @DenisTsay это уже другой вопрос...... читай (или задавай вопрос) про битовые операции...  `<<` и `>>`